# Change value with SQL, datetime error

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Aim: Update `NextDue` when `Priority` has a requested value. `NextDue` is updated with a date from `CurrentDate` plus `x` days.

Edit/Update: `CurrentDate` is an actual field and not todays date. I'll rename this going forwards.

Error:

> Conversation failed when converting datetime from character string)

Code:

```
   Update TblDates
   SET  Priority =  CASE
                      WHEN Priority='A' then NextDue + (CurrentDate +30)
                      WHEN Priority='B' then NextDue + (CurrentDate +730)
                   END
   WHERE NextFRADue in ('A','B')
```

Field type:

```
Priority  = Text
NextFRADue = DateTime
CurrentDate = DateTime
```

Date stored as "YYYY-MM-DD"

Comment: Which dbms? (Too many dbms products aren't ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to Date/time...)

Comment: You are updating `Priority`(text) with a `DateTime`, also, you want to update `NextDue` instead.

Comment: Using SQL Express 2005 in this instance.

Comment: Tim what do I need to change to edit the right field, I was sure I was right bar the date but if you can point it out that's be great

Comment: You are saying that CurentDate is a DateTime field, but your last line says 'Date stored as YYY-MM-DD'. Is it text or is it DateTime?

Comment: DateTime, I input the dates into the date field (which I regretting calling 'CurrentDate' in my test!) as YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First off:**
You are misinterpreting the syntax of an update statement.
With the way you are writing them, you are expecting to update `NextDate` with `DATEADD()` while it all has something to do with `LastDate`, on a case of `Priority`.

The basic syntax of the update statement (as per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx))

```
UPDATE <TableName>
   SET <Column That Will Be Updated> = <Statement that determines the new value>,
       <Column That Will Be Updated> = <Statement that determines the new value>
 WHERE <Normal where clause>
```

Your comment of with code below therefore is incorrect.

> What I need to do is change the field "NextDate" based on the field "LastDate".
>   NextDate will be a set amount of days forward from "LastDate" and this should be based on the value is a third field "Priority"
>
> ```
>     Update TBLTEST  
>        SET LastDate = CASE WHEN Priority='1' THEN (NextDate+ DATEADD(Day, 30))  
>                            WHEN Priority='2' THEN (NextDate+ DATEADD(Day, 30))  
>                       END  
>      WHERE NextDate in ('1','2')
> ```

*Updated:*
From this, the code that you are looking for would be something like this:

```
UPDATE TblDates
       -- Update the column NextDue
   SET NextDue = CASE
                   -- Add NextDate number of days to the LastDate DateTime value, when the Priority value is 1
                   WHEN Priority='1' then DATEADD(day, (30+NextDate), LastDate)
                   -- Add NextDate number of days to the LastDate DateTime value, when the Priority value is 2
                   WHEN Priority='2' then DATEADD(day, (30+NextDate), LastDate)
                 END
 WHERE NextFRADue in ('1','1')
```

Further reading:
[MSDN: DATEADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

.
*Old answer since not sure which version was the one that was right for your question*
The code that you are looking for would be something like this:

```
Update TblDates
   SET NextDue = CASE
                   WHEN Priority='A' then DATEADD(day, 30, CurrentDate)
                   WHEN Priority='B' then DATEADD(day, 730, CurrentDate)
                 END
 WHERE NextFRADue in ('A','B')
```

Comment: Spot on, now I see it working it's 'obvious' :-) Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be several mistakes in our code snippet. In SQL Server you can use DATEADD to add your days:

```
 UPDATE  TblDates
 SET         NextDue= CASE WHEN Priority = 'A'
                      THEN DATEADD(DAY, 70, CurrentDate)
                      WHEN Priority = 'B'
                      THEN DATEADD(DAY, 730, CurrentDate)
                  END
 WHERE   NextFRADue IN ( 'A', 'B' )
```

I have also changed the query to update NextDue. In your code example you are adding `NextDue` to `DATEADD(DAY, <days>, CurrentDate)` and updating priority with this value.